# What is the difference between HANDLE and HFILE in WinAPI?

Tags: winapi, file

WinAPI OpenFile function returns HFILE, and GetFileTime for instance needs HANDLE. When I feed it with (HANDLE)some_hFile it seems to work fine. Is there any difference in this types, or one of these is simply rudimental?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OpenFile is a 16-bit Windows backward-compatibility function. CreateFile is the function to open files.

Answer (score 6):

If the function succeeds then HFILE is a file HANDLE.  If not, then it is an HFILE_ERROR constant (presumably -1).   The point is that it can't be a HANDLE on error so they return something that can be either a HANDLE or an error value.

See @Barry's suggestion as well.

Answer (score 4):

Years ago, `HANDLES` were 16-bit `int`s.  All handles everywhere in Windows were `HANDLES`.  Then someone realized that a file `HANDLE` wasn't quite the same thing as a window `HANDLE`, and if they were defined differently, say as `HFILE` and `HWND`, then maybe developers wouldn't accidentally interchange them as much.  (However they were both `typedef`'ed to `int`).

Later still, someone realized that if they were defined completely defferently...say as:

```
typedef struct _hfile {} * HFILE;
typedef struct _hwnd {} * HWND;
```

then the compiler itself would complain if you used one in place of the other, even if, in reality, each was just a plain old 16-bit (eventually 32-bit) `int` value.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, HANDLE is just an unsigned 32bit number defined as PVOID. It is a generic handle. HFILE is a specialized handle, although defined as signed 32bit number to be able to get value -1.
There are other specialized handles, like HACCEL, HBITMAP, HINSTANCE, etc., all defined as a dependence to HANDLE.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenFile returns a File Handle if succed or a HFILE_ERROR if it fails.