# Is an explicit cast always the same as an implicit conversion?

Tags: c, visual-studio, warnings

In Visual C I have:

```
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR)-1)
typedef int HFILE;
HFILE stat_fh = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

And I have the warning:

```
"..warning C4047: '=' : 'HFILE' differs in levels of indirection from 'HANDLE'"
```

Is it OK if I remove the warning by casting **INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE** to **HFILE** type?
I assume the compiler already does exactly the same thing automatically.

Comment: Unless I'm missing what you're trying to accomplish, you should be using `HFILE_ERROR` for your "invalid" `HFILE` handles.

Comment: You also should read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320893)

Comment: @mas.morozov: I've edited your edit. There's no such thing as an "implicit cast". See the second paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when both kinds of type conversions ("casts") are applicable - explicit and implicit - the semantics of the explicit conversion is exactly the same as the semantics of the implicit conversion.

Note though that in your case it is not obvious that implicit conversion is applicable. In WinodwsAPI `HANDLE` is typically defined as a pointer type. You are trying to convert it to `int` type. Standard C does not allow implicit conversion from pointer types to `int`. This means that the following declaration

```
HFILE stat_fh = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

contains a constraint vioolation. i.e. it is supposed to be non-compilable. So, your question is actually moot (assuming that converting a `HANDLE` to an `int` is really what you want to do). An explicit cast is the *only* option you have in this case.

If your compiler can do this conversion implicitly (with a mere warning), then it is just a quirk of your compiler, not related to standard C language at all.

Comment: It is related to the C language. The standard requires a *diagnostic* for any constraint violation or syntax error; it does not require that diagnostic to be a fatal error. A non-fatal warnings satisfies the standard's requirements. (The only case where the standard requires a translation unit to be *rejected* is when there's a `#error` directive.)

Comment: *both kinds of type conversions ("casts") are applicable - explicit and implicit* Only the explicit one is a cast. A cast is always explicit.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen to work, but it's not ok (though it seems to be what Microsoft expects; see below).

First of all, your terminology is a bit off.  A *cast* is an operator, consisting of a type name in parentheses. It specifies an explicit conversion. There is no such thing as an implicit cast or "auto cast". What you call a "forced cast" is merely a *cast*; what you call an "auto cast" is an *implicit conversion*.

`HFILE` is just another name for `int`. According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `HANDLE` is a typedef (alias) for `void*`. The language does not define an implicit conversion from any pointer type to `int`. In this case, your compiler is letting you get away with it and issuing a warning. In fact, the assignment is a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic message. Your compiler could have (and IMHO should have) simply rejected your program with a fatal error message.

If you have a pointer value, you should assign it to a pointer variable *of the same type*.

If you want to assign a `HANDLE` value to `stat_fh`, then you should declare `stat_fh` as a `HANDLE`, not as an `int` (or even as an `HFILE`, which as I said is merely another name for `int`).

<strike>Why have you defined `HFILE` as an alias for `int`?</strike>

**UPDATE :**

I see that `HFILE` is actually defined *by Microsoft* as:

```
typedef int HFILE;
```

Their documentation also says that `HFILE` is "A handle to a file opened by [OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)". If you follow those links, you'll see that `OpenFile` is not recommended.

On the other hand, the documentation for `OpenFile` says that a file opened by `OpenFile` (which returns an `HFILE`, i.e., an `int`) should be closed by passing the handle to [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which takes a `HANDLE` (i.e., `void*`) argument.

This is appalling, and I'd guess that this is part of the reason Microsoft has decided to discourage the use of `OpenFile`.

As far as I can tell (though I'm not a Windows programmer so I could be missing something), there's no good reason to use `HFILE`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Keith in theory, but in reality the core Win32 API is such a turd that you just get used to these kinds of problems.

Comment: @mas.morozov: I didn't realize that `HFILE` was a Microsoft definition. I'm appalled. But MS's documentation (see my link above) says that `HFILE` is returned by `OpenFile`, which is not recommended; `CreateFile`, the recommended function, returns a `HANDLE`.

Comment: Yes, as one of Windows programmers, I agree that there is no really good reason to use legacy `HFILE`, except where interacting with rare old legacy code that is using it. All other Microsoft handle types (`HWND`,`HICON` and so on) are defined in more proper way, like `typedef HANDLE HWND`.

Comment: Thanks for you help Keith, you surely clarified my problem, but I can't change the way my code is done, I want to simply remove the warning from the build log.